# Update и inner join

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы. В одной есть поля `id` и `Name`. В другой - `cityID` и `cityTitle_en`. Как написать такой update для второй таблицы, чтобы значение `cityTitle_en` соответствовало значению `Name` первой таблицы?

Comment: UPDATE какого поля необходимо сделать? вообще некрасиво будет если записей много

Comment: @sterx, update поля cityTitle_en. Записей около 1к

Comment: UPDATE  table_2 t2 SET cityTitle_en = (SELECT Name FROM table_1 t1 WHERE t1.id=t2.cityID)
если связь по ид

Comment: @sterx, спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объединить как при обычном селекте. В update указать обновляемую, в set какое поле какому присвоить, например:

```
update table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2 on <condition>
set t1.field = t2.field
```